# Node Js Server Is Not Starting on Localhost - Stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have been struggling for a while with starting nodejs server,

server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(index);
}).listen(9615);
```

But it's been stuck forever. No server is starting.

[image]

Would really appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Have you tried to send a requests? Your code looks fine. Open a new terminal tab and try `curl http://localhost:9615`

Comment: I am noob with nodejs yet. how to send requests? please

Comment: hey, it showing plain html at http://localhost:9615

Comment: That means your server works fine.

Comment: If you want html to be rendered rather than plain text change the `Content-Type` to `text/html`

Comment: yes, i get it now. But it is showing plain html, (as written in code to show plain html) How can i run index.html as .html not plain text

Comment: Great it works fine

Comment: Thank you very much :) God bless you Mark.